# Regex find numbers in specific position

Tags: python, regex

hi i have a string like this

```
track._Event('product', 'test');Product.lisen(1234, 21, 4343); return false;
```

i want to use some regular expression so i would end up with groups

```
pid = 1234
p1 = 21
p2 = 4343
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

s = "track._Event('product', 'test');Product.lisen(1234, 21, 4343); return false;"

pattern = re.compile(r'.*lisen\((?P<pid>\d+),\s*(?P<p1>\d+),\s*(?P<p2>\d+)\).*')

pid, p1, p2 =  map(int, pattern.match(s).groups())
```

Note: I used named capturing groups, but that is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why regular expression? you can do it will simple string manipulations

```
>>> s="track._Event('product', 'test');Product.lisen(1234, 21, 4343); return false;"
>>> s.split("lisen(")[-1].split(")")[0].split(",")
['1234', ' 21', ' 4343']
```